# ASP.NET MVC inline tags not working with <link href>

Tags: asp.net

Every time I put an inline tag on the link's href attribute it somehow gets auto-encoded. Is this ASP.NET's default behavior?  How can I dynamically set the Href attribute using code?  This is in MVC btw.

Attempted something like this

```
<link href="<%: Link.Content.Jquery_css %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

which rendered this (nothing changed)

```
<link href="<%: Link.Content.Jquery_css %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

and this

```
<link href="<%= Link.Content.Jquery_css %> rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

which produced this (I couldn't remember the exact numbers, but it seems the bracket-percent-equals was encoded to link format)

```
<link href="/View/Shared%25Link.Content.Jquery_css%25" %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

`Link.Content.Jquery_css` is a strongly typed string containing the link made using T4MVC.

Add'l info: I used ASP.NET MVC 2, in .NET 4 and testing in Firefox.

Comment: what does `Link.Content.Jquery_css` look like when you do `Response.Write(Link.Content.Jquery_css)`? Is it being encoded before it hits the view?

Comment: Seems like it is.  I'm just confused since I'm using the same Link.Content class for a javascript reference on the same master page `<script src=<%= Link.Content.Jquery_js%> />` and it's working as expected.

Comment: You'll have to trace back to the creation of that element. Can you show some code from either the Model or the Controller where the Jquery_css is being created?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's a static readonly string. I don't have the source code at the moment. I'll post additional details if things still don't work later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's getting auto-encoded because of the tag your using (`<%: %>`). If you don't want the URL to be Encoded, use the following:

```
<link href="<%= Link.Content.Jquery_css %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I forgot to say that I've tried it already. Edited my question to clarify it.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same issue in the master page.  (It doesn't happen in an individual page.)  I found removing "runat=server" from the head tag fixed the problem.

Comment: +1, my issue was with webforms, but removing runat="server" did fix up the exact problem the OP had (with it not interpreting the code)

Answer (score 3):

Change the ":" to "=" and that remove the auto encoding

Answer (score 1):

Your view is unable to access Link.Content.Jquery_css property. ASP.NET unhelpfully doesn't throw any error.

Move that line inside the body of the page and you will see compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "<%= ResolveUrl("~/content/styles.css") %>";
        @import "<%= ResolveUrl("~/content/print.css") %>" print;
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Cool! I should have thought about this! All the above ideas didn't work. Not to mention that runat="server" isn't even relevant here (MVC). Thanks!